# The number of overlapping events SQL

Tags: sqlite, time, intervals, overlap

Hello everyone I'm trying to solve the following problem: let's say I have a table with

| event_type | chat | time_start | time_end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | chat 1 | 15:01:21 | 15:04:20 |
| A | chat 2 | 15:00:13 | 15:03:10 |
| A | chat 3 | 15:03:00 | 15:17:00 |
| A | chat 4 | 14:50:00 | 15:03:05 |
| B | chat 1 | 17:00:00 | 17:30:00 |

My goal is to output for each event_type and each chat the number of intersections with other chats.
That is, I want the result to look like this

| event_type | chat | Number of intersections |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | chat 1 | 4 |
| A | chat 2 | 4 |
| A | chat 3 | 4 |
| A | chat 4 | 4 |
| B | chat 1 | 0 |

I understand that I can use JON, but my real database is very large, and it does not load join's.
So I thought of the following query

```
WITH T1
WITH Intervals AS (
    SELECT 
        time_start AS Event_time,
        1 AS cnt,
        event_type
    FROM 
        events
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        time_end AS Event_time,
        -1 AS cnt,
        event_type
    FROM 
        events
)
SELECT 
        event_type, chat,
        SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY event_type ORDER BY Event_time) AS Cumulative_count
 FROM 
        Intervals
 GROUP BY   event_type,chat.
```

But the result is not what I need. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want:-

[image]

i.e. as per

> My goal is to output for each event_type and each chat the number of intersections with **other** chats.

- "chat 1 type A" will intersect with "chat 2", "chat 3" and "chat 4" **not itself** and not **chat 1 type B**.
- etc
- "chat 1 type B" will intersect with nothing

then you could use:-

```
SELECT 
    event_type,
    chat,
    (
        SELECT count() 
        FROM events AS t2 
        WHERE
            t2.rowid <> t1.rowid
            AND
                (
                    t1.time_start BETWEEN t2.time_start AND t2.time_end
                    OR
                    t1.time_end BETWEEN t2.time_start AND t2.time_end
                )
    ) AS NOI
FROM events AS t1 
ORDER BY event_type,chat
;
```

- this does assume that the table is not a `WITHOUT ROWID` table, although you could use `t2.event_type||t2.chat <> t1.event_type||t1.chat`, instead of  `t2.rowid <> t1.rowid` to achieve the same result.
- if you wanted the results as per your expected results i.e. to include the chat itself as one of the intersections but only if there are intersections then  you could replace `count()` with `count() + (count() > 0)` and thus get:- [image]